# Measurement of two qubits in a tensor product space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurements

I understand that if we have two qubits, say $\Psi \in \mathcal{H}_1 \bigotimes \mathcal{H}_2$ where Alice has the first qubit, and she makes a measurement and ends up with the state $\phi \in \mathcal{H}_1$ then the full state after this measurement would be $P (\Psi)$ where $P$ is the projection given by $P = |\phi\rangle \langle \phi|\bigotimes I$.

My question is how do we deal with a system like $\mathcal{H}_1 \bigotimes \mathcal{H}_2 \bigotimes \mathcal{H}_3 \bigotimes \mathcal{H}_4$ in which Alice has, for example, qubits 1 and 3 and she makes a measurement and finds a state $\phi \in \mathcal{H}_1 \bigotimes \mathcal{H}_3$ what sort of projection do we use now to find out the full state after the measurement? I guess in the separable case when $\phi = \phi_1 \bigotimes \phi_3$ we would simply use the projection $|\phi_1 \rangle \langle \phi_1| \bigotimes I \bigotimes |\phi_3 \rangle \langle \phi_3| \bigotimes I$ but I'm unsure how to generalise this to a general state.

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: Let $\mathcal{H}_a = \mathcal{H}_1\otimes\mathcal{H}_3$. This reduces the problem to the first case

Comment: But what about the order of the tensor products is this not important?

Comment: if $\mathcal{H}_b$ is the product of the other two spaces then $\mathcal{H}_1\otimes\mathcal{H}_2\otimes\mathcal{H}_3\otimes\mathcal{H}_4 = \mathcal{H}_a\otimes\mathcal{H}_b$. projecting from this space onto $\mathcal{H}_a$ is the problem you solved in your first paragraph

Comment: Okay great - so in fact order is not important in a tensor product?

Comment: Yes and no. strictly $V\otimes U \ne U \otimes V$. However the two spaces are isomorphic, so which way round you chose to write them in the first place was just an arbitrary notational decision.